# Does this inequality hold in general : Please verify

Tags: inequality

> Let $r>1$, $i<j$ where $r$ is a real number and $i$ and $j$ are positive integers.
>   Whether this inequality holds in general: $$\frac{r^j-1}{r^{\big(\frac{3j}{2}\big)}-1}<\frac{r^i-1}{r^{\big(\frac{3i}{2}\big)}-1} ?$$

I have done this:the given inequality is equivalent to:
$$r^{j}r^{\big(\frac{3i}{2}\big)}-r^j-r^{\big(\frac{3i}{2}\big)}<r^{i}r^{\big(\frac{3j}{2}\big)}-r^i-r^{\big(\frac{3j}{2}\big)}.$$
I don't know what to do next.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you computed a few values? How about the deeivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $x=r^{i/2}$ and $y=r^{j/2}$ then $y\gt x\gt1$ and the inequality holds if and only if
$$
(y^2-1)(x^3-1)\lt(x^2-1)(y^3-1).
$$
Let $u(x,y)$ denote the RHS minus the LHS, then
$$
u(x,y)=x^2y^3-x^3y^2-y^3+x^3+y^2-x^2,
$$
hence
$$
u(x,y)=(y-x)(x-1)(y-1)(xy+x+y).
$$
One sees that $u(x,y)\gt0$ for every $y\gt x\gt1$. QED.